# Unique setInterval value for each Object instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 instances of object "Ball" that move right at a rate of 1 pixel. At the same time, I want them to move at separate speeds - to each have a unique setInterval value.

Originally, I had them set to move right at separate pixel rates, but that makes collision detection (when used in another project) a bit wonky.  Here's my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

balls = [];
FPS = 1000/60;

function Speed(ballSpeed) {

    this.ballSpeed = ballSpeed;
}

function Ball() {
    var rNum = Math.random() + 1;   
    var rate = Math.round(rNum*10)/10;
    var ballDrop = $('<div />').addClass('ball');
    this.speed = new Speed(rate);
    this.output = ballDrop.appendTo($(".container"));   
}

Ball.prototype = {
    updatePos: function() {             
        bL = this.output.position().left;
        this.output.css({left: bL += 1});   
        this.output.text(this.speed.ballSpeed); 
    }

}

var ballRate = setInterval(function() {
    balls.forEach(function(ball){
        ball.updatePos();   
        if (bL === 580) {
        window.clearInterval(ballRate);
        }           
    });

}, FPS);

function addBall() {
    ball = new Ball(10, 20);
    balls.push(ball);
    }

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    addBall();
    }

});
```

I keep wanting to do something like the following, but it doesn't work...

```
balls.forEach(function(ball){
    var ballRate = setInterval(function() {
        ball.updatePos();   
        if (bL === 580) {
            window.clearInterval(ballRate);
        }           
    }, ball.speed.ballSpeed);

});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghostClinic/76QpJ/8/)

Comment: 1 pixel per what? Don't measure time in animation frames!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: you should define some `run` method for the Ball class, call it to start running the ball, of course each run method should have the core `setInterval` called and the interval time should be different (particular to each ball), like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/76QpJ/9/

Comment: you use bL for all three balls, that wont work

Comment: @Alex the `bL` is just used to know where to stop the ball. Of course he used it in a wrong way so the balls run forever without stopping. But his problem is not that part. He wants separate `setInterval` for each ball.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some problems: If you replace your setInterval code with the second variant you showed, then you have to move it to **below the balls are instantiated**. (because the loop is executed only once and if the balls aren't instantiated, the code won't run because there are no balls to iterate over.

also, your bL variable is shared across all balls, so in order to have different speeds you have to change bL to this.bL and ball.bL

Last but not least, the ball speed difference is too small to make it possible to see it. (how would you distinguish 1000 times per second with 999 times per second?), so I suggest you to change the ball.speed.ballSpeed in your setInterval to FPS * ball.speed.ballSpeed.

Also, it seems that the arguments to the Ball constructor are unused, so I suggest to remove those.

```
Code to let me add jsFiddle link
```

JSfiddle of working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js8N2/)

hope I could help, Ferdi265

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to actually use the induvidual speed of each ball.

Here is an update of the code.

```
Ball.prototype = {
    updatePos: function() {             
        bL = this.output.position().left;
        if(bL < 580) {
            this.output.css({left: bL += this.speed.ballSpeed});    
            this.output.text(this.speed.ballSpeed);
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

and

```
var ballRate = setInterval(function() {
    var keepUpdating = [];
    balls.forEach(function(ball){
        keepUpdating.push(ball.updatePos());                
    });
    if(keepUpdating.indexOf(true) === -1) {
        window.clearInterval(ballRate);
    }
}, FPS);
```

The keepUpdating is because the balls have different speed, so the interval needs to stop when the last ball crosses the finish.